# Average value of function of two variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions

I'm wondering how to determine the average value of a function of two intervals, both of which have given bounds. Say the function f[x,y] (below) has bounds x,y=[0,5]. How would I go about this? I assume by using the integration function, but I've only done that with a function of 1 variable.

```
f[x_, y_] := Sqrt[1 + .25 y^2 ((2.5 + 1.5 Cos[Pi/3 t] - 2.75)^2 + 
  (2.4 + 1.1 Sin[Pi/3 t] - 3.75)^2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, y_] := 
  Sqrt[1 + .25 y^2 ((2.5 + 1.5 Cos[Pi/3 t] - 2.75)^2 + (2.4 + 
            1.1 Sin[Pi/3 t] - 3.75)^2)] /. z_Real :> Rationalize[z] // 
   Simplify;
```

The average of `f[x, y]` is dependent on `t`

```
avg[t_] = Integrate[f[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]/25

(* (32 ArcSinh[
     1/4 Sqrt[723/2 - 75 Cos[(π t)/3] + 52 Cos[(2 π t)/3] - 
       297 Sin[(π t)/3]]] + √((723 - 150 Cos[(π t)/3] + 
        104 Cos[(2 π t)/3] - 594 Sin[(π t)/3]) (755 - 
        150 Cos[(π t)/3] + 104 Cos[(2 π t)/3] - 
        594 Sin[(π t)/3])))/(8 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[
   723 - 150 Cos[(π t)/3] + 104 Cos[(2 π t)/3] - 594 Sin[(π t)/3]]
   ) *)

{tmin, tmax} = FindArgMin[avg[t], {t, #}] & /@ {-2 Pi, 2 Pi} // Flatten

(* {-4.64142, 7.35858} *)
```

Plotting the average as a function of `t`

```
Plot[avg[t], {t, tmin, tmax}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]